Shopify CLI 3.x running "shopify theme dev" getting- FetchError: "socket hang up" on API request
I'm encountering an issue while trying to develop my Shopify theme locally using the command shopify theme dev. When running this command, I receive the following error:
FetchError: request to https://hope2build.myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable/themes/145238884571/assets/bulk.json failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@shopify/cli/dist/chunk-3WDAYAS7.js:43616:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

The error seems to be related to a socket hang up when trying to fetch assets from the Shopify API. I am running this on a development store in a partner account and using the latest version of Shopify CLI.
Steps I’ve Tried:

Verified my internet connection.
Confirmed that the store URL is correct.
Ensured that I’m logged into the correct store using shopify login --store.
-Tried running the command in different networks.

System Information:
OS: Windows 10
Node.js version: v20.11.0
Shopify CLI version: 3.67.2
I expected the command shopify theme dev to start a local server, allowing me to preview my theme changes in the browser while syncing those changes to my Shopify development store automatically. Instead, the process fails with a "socket hang up" error.
